# Display additional class value for each first record in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want use the following class value to the first record of my ListView:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <div class="active">
         <!-- something here -->
     </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and use

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <div>
         <!-- something here -->
     </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

to my other records.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ListView something like this should work:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <div class='<%#(int)DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex") == 0 ? "active" : ""%>'>
         <!-- something here -->
     </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Also you might consider CSS for this:

```
.parentClass div:first-child {
    /* content of the active class goes here */
}
```